# Pundit Badge for only 8 questions

Tags: support, badges, comment-badges

I see my mistake now (see original question  below).  I was thinking pundit was for answers not comments.

I've a follow up question: how I can see the upvotes on my comments.  Any ideas?

---

See screen shot, I got the Pundit badge but I've only 8 with 5 or more.  Not that I'm complaining, just honest.
[image]

Comment: You're talking about questions in title and 1st paragraph, but you're circling answers (and yes, pundit is for comments, not answers nor questions)

Comment: @Balus : Clearly I need a weekend at this point on a friday.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pundit is for comments, not answers.

Comment: Does it sill exist? Can´t find this badge.

Answer (score 7):

Addressing your follow-up question, there are at least two [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) queries that come to mind:

- [This one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution?UserId=215752) will give you a quick overview of your comment score distribution.
- [This one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/16440/my-latest-comments?UserId=215752) will show your latest 500 comments sorted chronologically, along with their score.

Comment: Thanks of course SEDE is old, but that works.  Hard to pick a correct answer when there are two; hope you understand Jim was first.

Comment: Is there a way to get the scores _and_ links to the comments? I am wondering if there is something like the second variant, but not chronological order. I would like to have score order without downloading the csv file. I guess this line should be changed in the query: `order by CreationDate DESC` to `order by Votes DESC` or so, but I am not sure if there is already a ready-made query url for this like the one above.